# The IMAP application (Using Pantomime) is crashing whenever a new mail is opened

Tags: cocoa, imap, pantomime

I am able to show the new mail headers but not able to open the body of the new mail.So,I am rebuilding the Cache Manager every time the new mail comes but then the application is getting crashed when accessing the new mail.If i do not rebuild the cache everytime a new mail is received then the mails get doubled in the local folder.These cache manager changes are made in the **Pantomime framework** code .
 Please suggest if there is some other way to open the new mail body.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly Your application get crash is not the problem due to the cache manager rebuilding because for your cache manager there must be a unique mail file for every mail. While opening the mail you should use the setMessageInitialized method of the pantomime for fetching the body of the new mails and then append that file to your local storage.